# Issue with Dynamic Cart Page Rendering using Async Thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am currently working on a React project and have encountered an issue with the rendering of the CartPage component. After adding a new product to the cart, the CartPage component does not render the updated cart items until the page is manually refreshed. I have checked the console logs and observed that the state is being updated correctly after fetching the cart items, but the rendering is not reflecting the changes immediately.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import api from '../../api'
import { AxiosError } from 'axios'
import { CartState } from '../../types/types'

const initialState: CartState = {
  cartItems: [],
  totalItems: 0,
  totalPrice: 0,
  error: null,
  isLoading: false,
  cartLength: 0
}
//** Add To Cart Thunks */
export const addToCartThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'cart/addToCart',
  async (
    { productId, quantity, token }: { productId: string; quantity: number; token: string | null },
    { rejectWithValue }
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.post(
        '/api/cart',
        { productId, quantity },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        }
      )
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response?.data)
      }
    }
  }
)

//** Get Cart Items */
export const getCartItemsThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'cart/getCartItems',
  async (token: string | null, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get('/api/cart', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })

      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response?.data)
      }
    }
  }
)

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    //** Add To Cart Reducers */
    builder
      .addCase(addToCartThunk.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(addToCartThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.cartItems = action.payload.cartItems
        state.totalItems = action.payload.totalItems
        state.totalPrice = action.payload.totalPrice
      })
      .addCase(addToCartThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
        const errorMsg = action.payload
        if (typeof errorMsg === 'string') {
          state.error = errorMsg
        }
        state.isLoading = false
        return state
      })

      //** Get Cart Items Reducers */
      .addCase(getCartItemsThunk.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(getCartItemsThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.cartItems = action.payload.cartItems
        state.totalItems = action.payload.totalItems
        state.totalPrice = action.payload.totalPrice
      })
      .addCase(getCartItemsThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
        const errorMsg = action.payload
        if (typeof errorMsg === 'string') {
          state.error = errorMsg
        }
        state.isLoading = false
        return state
      })
  }
})

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { getCartItemsThunk } from '../../redux/slices/cartSlice';
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from '../../redux/store';
import { getTokenFromStorage } from '../../utils/token';

export default function CartPage() {
  const { cartItems, totalPrice, isLoading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = getTokenFromStorage();

    console.log("Token:", token);

    if (token) {
      dispatch(getCartItemsThunk(token))
    }
  }, []);

  console.log("Rendering CartPage with cartItems:", cartItems);


  //** Checkout Handler */
  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    swal({
      title: 'Checkout',
      text: 'Your order has been received successfully',
      icon: 'success',
    }).then((isOk) => {
      if (isOk) {
        navigate('/products');
      }
    });
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Your cart is empty.</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          {cartItems.map((product) => (
            <div key={product.product._id}>{product.product.name}</div>
          ))}
          <div>Total Price: ${totalPrice}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Console Logs:

Token: i got token
Cart Items after fetching:
Rendering CartPage with cartItems:
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{product: {…}, quantity: 4, _id: '657caf13399eb2072f240ffd'}
1
:
{product: {…}, quantity: 2, _id: '657cb8a1399eb2072f241199'}

and when i add new item then go to cart page i got this

```
The above error occurred in the <CartPage> component:

at CartPage (http://localhost:3000/src/pages/cart/CartPage.tsx?t=1702676943521:28:7)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=ddbf63b5:3405:5)
```

when i add new product to cart it added seccessfully,
[image]

After adding a new item to the cart, the cart page does not dynamically update to display the newly added item. The entire webpage appears white

[image]

and I only see the updated cart items after manually refreshing the page.
[image]

I expect the cart page to display the newly added item immediately without requiring a manual page refresh.

Comment: What is the error being produced by this code? Please [edit] to clarify what the issue or problem is, including complete error messages and any accompanying error stacktraces. See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I've included some images to help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshots of the responses, it looks like the POST request to add an item to the cart returns a response object of a different shape than the GET request to return the cart. The GET returns a response object with `message` and `cartItems` keys, and the `getCartItemsThunk.fulfilled` reducer case correctly accesses these properties from the action payload. ***However***, the POST appears to return a response object with `message` and `cart` properties, but the `addToCartThunk.fulfilled` case is attempting to reference still a `cartItems` property. I suspect you just need to access into the action payload the correct properties, e.g. `action.payload.cart.products` for the cart items array.

The rejected case reducers are also incorrectly mutating the draft copy ***and*** returning it. They should only ever do one or the other, but never both. See [Direct State Mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation) for specific details.

```js
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // ** Add To Cart Reducers **
    builder
      .addCase(addToCartThunk.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(addToCartThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { payload } = action;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.cartItems = payload.cart.products;
        state.totalItems = payload./* whatever this access should be to totalItems */;
        state.totalPrice = payload./* whatever this access should be to totalPrice */;
      })
      .addCase(addToCartThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
        const errorMsg = action.payload;
        if (typeof errorMsg === 'string') {
          state.error = errorMsg;
        }
        state.isLoading = false;
      })

      // ** Get Cart Items Reducers **
      .addCase(getCartItemsThunk.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getCartItemsThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.cartItems = action.payload.cartItems;
        state.totalItems = action.payload.totalItems;
        state.totalPrice = action.payload.totalPrice;
      })
      .addCase(getCartItemsThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
        const errorMsg = action.payload;
        if (typeof errorMsg === 'string') {
          state.error = errorMsg;
        }
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
  }
});
```